# How to fix sql code that is running twice

Tags: php, sql

I have a select query from my database which is working fine but when I run my sql insert query it is adding the insert twice into my database.

I've tried so many things that I am lost on what else I could try.

```
<?php 
session_start();
include_once("db.php");

$loggenOnUser=$_SESSION["user_id"];

$plannumber = "SELECT * FROM goals WHERE uid = $loggenOnUser ORDER BY 
plannumber DESC LIMIT 1";
$duration = $conn->query($plannumber);
while($record = $duration->fetch_array()){
$total = $record['plannumber']+1;
}

?>

<body>
  <?php 

    $sql = "INSERT INTO goals (uid, plannumber, remainingdays)
            VALUES 
             ('$loggenOnUser', '$total', '90')";

        if (mysqli_query($conn,$sql)) {
            echo "New records created successfully";
        } else {
            echo "";
        }
    mysqli_close($conn);
 ?>

</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to add a new record into the database with the column plannumber increasing my 1

Here is the new code and it is running the code twice.

```
<?php 
session_start();
include_once("db.php");

$loggedOnUser=$_SESSION["user_id"];

$plannumber = "SELECT * FROM goals WHERE uid = $loggedOnUser ORDER BY 
plannumber DESC 
LIMIT 1";
$duration = $conn->query($plannumber);
while($record = $duration->fetch_array()){
$total = $record['plannumber']+1;
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO goals (uid, plannumber, remainingdays)
    VALUES 
     ('$loggedOnUser', '$total', '90'),
     ('$loggedOnUser', '$total', '89'),
     ('$loggedOnUser', '$total', '88'),
     ('$loggedOnUser', '$total', '87'),
     ('$loggedOnUser', '$total', '86'),
     ('$loggedOnUser', '$total', '85'),
     ('$loggedOnUser', '$total', '84'),
     ('$loggedOnUser', '$total', '83'),
     ('$loggedOnUser', '$total', '82'),
     ('$loggedOnUser', '$total', '81'),
     ('$loggedOnUser', '$total', '80'),
     ('$loggedOnUser', '$total', '79'),
     ('$loggedOnUser', '$total', '78'),
     ('$loggedOnUser', '$total', '77'),
     ('$loggedOnUser', '$total', '76'),
     ('$loggedOnUser', '$total', '75'),
     ('$loggedOnUser', '$total', '74'),
     ('$loggedOnUser', '$total', '73'),
     ('$loggedOnUser', '$total', '72'),
     ('$loggedOnUser', '$total', '71'),
     ('$loggedOnUser', '$total', '70'),
     ('$loggedOnUser', '$total', '69'),
     ('$loggedOnUser', '$total', '68'),
     ('$loggedOnUser', '$total', '67'),
     ('$loggedOnUser', '$total', '66'),
     ('$loggedOnUser', '$total', '65'),
     ('$loggedOnUser', '$total', '64'),
     ('$loggedOnUser', '$total', '63'),
     ('$loggedOnUser', '$total', '62'),
     ('$loggedOnUser', '$total', '61'),
     ('$loggedOnUser', '$total', '60'),
     ('$loggedOnUser', '$total', '59'),
     ('$loggedOnUser', '$total', '58'),
     ('$loggedOnUser', '$total', '57'),
     ('$loggedOnUser', '$total', '56'),
     ('$loggedOnUser', '$total', '55'),
     ('$loggedOnUser', '$total', '54'),
     ('$loggedOnUser', '$total', '53'),
     ('$loggedOnUser', '$total', '52'),
     ('$loggedOnUser', '$total', '51'),
     ('$loggedOnUser', '$total', '50'),
     ('$loggedOnUser', '$total', '49'),
     ('$loggedOnUser', '$total', '48'),
     ('$loggedOnUser', '$total', '47'),
     ('$loggedOnUser', '$total', '46'),
     ('$loggedOnUser', '$total', '45'),
     ('$loggedOnUser', '$total', '44'),
     ('$loggedOnUser', '$total', '43'),
     ('$loggedOnUser', '$total', '42'),
     ('$loggedOnUser', '$total', '41'),
     ('$loggedOnUser', '$total', '40'),
     ('$loggedOnUser', '$total', '39'),
     ('$loggedOnUser', '$total', '38'),
     ('$loggedOnUser', '$total', '37'),
     ('$loggedOnUser', '$total', '36'),
     ('$loggedOnUser', '$total', '35'),
     ('$loggedOnUser', '$total', '34'),
     ('$loggedOnUser', '$total', '33'),
     ('$loggedOnUser', '$total', '32'),
     ('$loggedOnUser', '$total', '31'),
     ('$loggedOnUser', '$total', '30'),
     ('$loggedOnUser', '$total', '29'),
     ('$loggedOnUser', '$total', '28'),
     ('$loggedOnUser', '$total', '27'),
     ('$loggedOnUser', '$total', '26'),
     ('$loggedOnUser', '$total', '25'),
     ('$loggedOnUser', '$total', '24'),
     ('$loggedOnUser', '$total', '23'),
     ('$loggedOnUser', '$total', '22'),
     ('$loggedOnUser', '$total', '21'),
     ('$loggedOnUser', '$total', '20'),
     ('$loggedOnUser', '$total', '19'),
     ('$loggedOnUser', '$total', '18'),
     ('$loggedOnUser', '$total', '17'),
     ('$loggedOnUser', '$total', '16'),
     ('$loggedOnUser', '$total', '15'),
     ('$loggedOnUser', '$total', '14'),
     ('$loggedOnUser', '$total', '13'),
     ('$loggedOnUser', '$total', '12'),
     ('$loggedOnUser', '$total', '11'),
     ('$loggedOnUser', '$total', '10'),
     ('$loggedOnUser', '$total', '9'),
     ('$loggedOnUser', '$total', '8'),
     ('$loggedOnUser', '$total', '7'),
     ('$loggedOnUser', '$total', '6'),
     ('$loggedOnUser', '$total', '5'),
     ('$loggedOnUser', '$total', '4'),
     ('$loggedOnUser', '$total', '3'),
     ('$loggedOnUser', '$total', '2'),
     ('$loggedOnUser', '$total', '1')";

if (mysqli_query($conn,$sql)) {
    echo "New records created successfully";
} else {
    echo "";
}
mysqli_close($conn);

header("Location: http://www.example.com/goals");
?>
```

The output is a set of records with one plannumber and another set of records with plannumber + 1.

I am new to coding so what would I be looking for that may be calling the query a second time?

Comment: Well your $sql variable needs to contain a valid SQL query string. The '"' needs to be closed after the SQL query. So replace '90'); with '90');"

Comment: Thank you. I added that but it is still added 2 new records to the database.

Comment: The reason is somewhere else, this file was not even inserting anything since mysqli_query was never called due to the double quote typo

Comment: This code does not reproduce the stated error. You need to do some more debugging of the rest of your application to work out where the problem might be coming from

Comment: Maybe a trigger set on your database. Please, check it and be sure.

Comment: I did some more testing and when I delete the </html> at the end, it causes 2 records to be created. When I add a <html> above the <body>, it causes the same error.

Comment: The php works fine but when I add <html><body></body></html> to the end of the php code, it causes duplicate records posted to the database.

Comment: I am trying the code on a different computer on a different network and it is working fine. Would it be getting caught in the cache and running again on the other computer?